# Anti-aliasing UIimage looks blurred or jagged

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimageview, uiimage

i want to draw 12 images in a circle representing the watch numbers, i have read all topics on stackoverflow regarding images with transparent border but it's not working in my case

```c
-(UIImage *)addImageNumber_:(UIImage *)img {

    int w = img.size.width;
    int h = img.size.height;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);
    CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context,YES);
    CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing( context ,YES );
    CGAffineTransform transform;

    for (int x=0; x<=11; x++) {

        UIImage *timg1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];

        CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, timg1.size.width+2, timg1.size.height+2);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size);
        [timg1 drawInRect:CGRectMake(1,1,timg1.size.width,timg1.size.height)];
        timg1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake((w-26)/2, 0, 26, 30), timg1.CGImage);

        transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-w/2, -w/2));
        transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians(30)));
        transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(transform, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(w/2, w/2));

        CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);
    }

    CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```

```c
UIViewEdgeAntialiasing = YES;
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
UIImage *img2 = [self addImageNumber_:img ];
R1.image = img2;
[self.view addSubview:R1];
```

test img is the background of the watch , 2.png is a transparent png with transparent borders

[image]

numbers at 12'o clock and 6'o clock looks ok because they are not rotated the rest are jaggy

[image: draw with text]

Comment: Antialiasing shouldn't be an issue with UIImageViews as they are antialiased by default as opposed to UIView's which are often shown as jagged. I think this could be another problem. Are you drastically shrinking the image you're using?

Comment: none of the images have been shrinked they all have the original size

Comment: The quality you get is what's technically possible. When you create the original image, an optimal anti-aliasing is used. When you then rotate it, it's no longer optimal. It simply lose quality with each transformation. It would be better to use text drawing functions to create the clock.

Comment: that was the initial way but it's even more blurred so i decided to go image way

Comment: Images are ALWAYS going to be more blurry than actual text. @Codo is right. If you you're only using images because your first try at text didn't work, try again.

Comment: i'm using a custom font papyrus and even for a label with all workarounds i'm not able to align vertically a text i have a limited height to draw the numbers

Comment: i have added a drawing with text and the text it's not to clear

Comment: Explain what this R1 thing is, please.

Comment: R1 is a 320/320 white background which will be an artwork for the clock

Comment: Yes but what is it? Because, again, if it's, say, a CALayer, it will be up to you to set the contentsScale correctly.

Comment: CGRect frame_01;
    frame_01 = CGRectMake(0.0, 70.0, 320.0, 320.0);
    UIImageView *R1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame_01];
    R1.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    R1.multipleTouchEnabled  = YES;
    R1.opaque = YES;

Answer (score 6):

Never say `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageRect.size)`. Say `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageRect.size, NO, 0)`. That way, on a double-resolution screen, you'll get a double-resolution graphics context.

You could even try a resolution value of 4 to increase the resolution even further.

Of course, the fact that you're starting with a pre-drawn image of a "2" might limit your resolution; you can't make a silk purse out of a sow's ear. You could be a lot better off drawing the "2" from scratch as a string.

Comment: i have attached an image with string instead of image but i still have antialiasing not working

Comment: But you didn't do what I said about drawing at a higher resolution, did you?

Comment: So you're not responding to what I said. Try what I said to try before you reject it.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
context!.interpolationQuality = .high
```