# Appearance of drawn circle on the apple watch is not smooth enough. How can I do it better?

Tags: swift, geometry, uiimage, watchkit, smoothing

One approach I tried is the following:

```
let circle = Circle.init()
let path = circle.path(in: kServiceRightFrame)
let serviceRightPath = UIBezierPath.init(cgPath: path.cgPath)
serviceRightPath.lineWidth = 2.0
serviceRightPath.fill()
serviceRightPath.stroke()
```

[image]

I played around with flatness too, but that did not get the job done either. How can a smoother looking circle be drawn programmatically?

EDIT:A more extensive view of my code:

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(kWatchInterfaceSize)
 let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

 //draw service path
 kSBScoreLabelFontColor.setStroke()
 kSBServiceBallColor.setFill()
 ---> code from above
    
 // Convert to UIImage
 let cgimage = context!.makeImage()
    
 //create scoreboardimage
 let scoreBoardImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgimage!)
    
  // End the graphics context'
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Comment: Looks like a bug given the simple code. I think it's worth checking which version this bug may have occurred and submit a bug report. Could also be other code you aren't including, such as how you draw it, transformations like scaling, etc.

Comment: Thanks George, you pointed out something really useful. I checked whether there was any scaling in the code and realised that, not any scaling was being used. I added a scaling factor, tried various out and eventually came to the result, I was hoping for. Big thanks again.

Comment: It would be useful to future readers to make answer that worked for you

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47178493/how-can-i-make-this-signature-view-more-clear-and-less-blur

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404877/anti-aliasing-uiimage-looks-blurred-or-jagged

Comment: Well I first had the suspicion that it had directly to do with the circle, I was drawing. And I looked for circle specifically, that is why those questions you mention did not show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

George put me on the right track. It was a scaling issue. The code that I changed was the following:

```
//Replaced this
//UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(kWatchInterfaceSize) 
//with this
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(kWatchInterfaceSize, 
false, 4.0)
```

That fixed it. Now the circle looks a lot smoother in appearance.
[image]